# Is there an iOS API for image editing in third party apps?

Tags: ios

Since iOS 8, the stock photos app can use third party image editing tools to edit photos. Is there an API that allows my own app to use the same third party apps for image editing within my app? UIDocumentInteractionController does not seem to allow that, but probably there's another way?

Comment: I looked for something like that too at some point. Doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLImageEditor library for image editing.
Here is a link for the sample project on github:
[Sample project](https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor)