# Add iOS Photo Editing to own app

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to edit photos in my own app.

I already impleted the UIImagePickerController but the only option there is `allowsEditing` which only let's me crop photos.

But I want to use the features like in the official photos app where I can add filters etc.

What do I have to implement? Or does anyone have a sample project?

Edit: For Clarification I want to use this "Official" Editor in my own app: http://www.imore.com/how-to-apply-filters-remove-redeye-photos-iphone-ipad

Comment: This is rather vague. You might want to search Github for repos, try this in google `ios development add photo filters site:github.com`. When I ran that search i found this which could be of use to you https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-ios

Comment: Well yeah. But like I said I wanted to know if I can use the apple made editor like in the photos app.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no API that lets a 3rd party app make use of photo editing extensions that happen to be installed on the device (or the built-in editor). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946693/is-there-an-ios-api-for-image-editing-in-third-party-apps

Comment: These filters are built into the system. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it. You can edit photos, yourself; you can supply editing extensions that the user can use; but you cannot see photo editing extensions supplied by other apps.

Answer (score 1):

The various filters that the Photos app uses are standard system CIFilters. See the [CIFilter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPhotoEffectChrome) particularly the section the `CIPhotoEffect*` filters. Those are the same filters used by the Photos application.